# In SQL how to check if a string contains a substring in(case insensitive)?

Tags: sql, psql

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%a%'
```

This works fine when case sensitive, but how to search case insensitively?

Thx ahead

Comment: Quel SQL? (Postgres has the `ILIKE` operator, which does exactly what you want, other implementations *may* have similar extensions)

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific DBMS you are using e.g. SQL Server, Oracle etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%a%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT * FROM products WHERE nam LIKE BINARY '%a%'
```

`collate` option can also be used and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) is how to make it case sensitive from mysql tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

searches for a substring within a larger string you can use   [CHARINDEX()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TSQL, you might want to specify a case insensitive collation while doing the search.

e.g.

```
create table tbl(str varchar(10))

insert into tbl values ('GaP'), ('GAP')

--This will only return 'GaP'
select * from tbl where str collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS like '%a%'

--This will return both values
select * from tbl where str collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS like '%a%'
```